# Calculating test grade averages without using arrays or min/max in C++

Tags: c++, function

Could anyone give me some pointers of the use of functions here? The assignment is as follows:

*> Write a program that calculates the average of a group of test scores, where the lowest score in the group is dropped.  It should use the following functions:

> - `void getScore()` should ask the user for a test score, store it in a reference parameter variable, and validate it.  This function should be called by `main` once for each of the 6 scores to be entered.  Use a local static variable for which score is to be entered.
> - `void calcAverage()` should calculate and display the average of the five highest scores.  This function should be called just once by `main` and should be passed the six scores.  Include 2 decimal places on the result.  This is passed data by value.
> - `double findLowest()` should find and return the lowest of the six scores passed to it.  It should be called by `calcAverage`, which uses the function to determine which of the six scores to drop.  This is passed data by value.
>
> Do not use the min or max C++ functions.*

What I'm failing to discover is how I can use a void function to pass data back to main. My code so far is a stringy mess of errors, but I'm not sure how else to approach this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double getScore(double);
double calcAverage(double);
double findLowest(double);

int main()
{
    
    double score = 0;
    double combinedScore = 0;


    getScore(score);

    calcAverage(combinedScore);

    findLowest();

}

double getScore(double score)
{
    double grade;
    int testNum = 1;

    cout << "Enter the test " << testNum << " grade :";
    cin >> grade;
    while (grade < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry! Must be at least zero.";
        cin >> grade;
    }
    while (testNum <= 6)
    {
        cout << "Enter the test " << testNum << " grade :";
        cin >> grade;
        if (grade < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry! Must be at least zero.";
            cin >> grade;
        }
        else
        testNum++;
        cout << "Enter the test " << testNum << " grade :";

        return (grade);
    }
}

void calcAverage()
{
    
}

double findLowest()
{

}
```

Comment: You can use references: _"store it in a reference parameter variable"_

Comment: That's what i'm stuck on. How do i do that with a void function? I thought references required a declared variable in main, which could then be passed in such as 
```
double getScore(double score)
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: Interpreting the instructions, it seems that you should be calling `getScore` six times, once for each grade.

Comment: You can mark parameters with `&` to tell C++ that it should be passed by reference, i.e. that the variable passed into the function should be the same as the variable in the function. This is used to effect variables outside of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i'm failing to discover is how i can use a void function to pass data back to int main.

One first step is to use a `void` function with reference:

```
#include <iostream>

void getScore(double& score)
{
    score = 4.0;
}

int main()
{
    double score = 0.;
    getScore(score);
    std::cout << score << std::endl;
}
```

That doesn't get your homework done, but it tells you one first thing you need to know.

Comment: Interesting. Could "float" be replaced by a 'regular', declared variable? We haven't gone over float in class as of yet

Comment: yeah, `float` and `double` are just as 'regular' as each other. I'll edit.